# NOPASSWD option not applying to second command

Tags: sudo, configuration

I'm sure that I'm just missing something really simple here, but I have the following sudoers file where I'm intending certain users to be allowed to run a couple of commands as the `repomgr` user without a passphrase:

```
lambda@host:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/repo
Cmnd_Alias REPO_LOAD_PASSPHRASE = /bin/bash -c /home/repomgr/preset-passphrase.sh
Cmnd_Alias REPO_PULL = /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/reprepro -b /var/packages/devel pull

%qa     ALL = (repomgr) NOPASSWD: REPO_LOAD_PASSPHRASE, \
              (repomgr) NOPASSWD: REPO_PULL
```

Now, the `REPO_LOAD_PASSPHRASE` command works fine; I run that and it doesn't prompt me for a password:

```
lambda@host:~$ sudo -K
lambda@host:~$ sudo -u repomgr -i /home/repomgr/preset-passphrase.sh
lambda@host:~$
```

However, the second command, the `REPO_PULL` command, continues to prompt me for a password despite the `NOPASSWD` setting:

```
lambda@host:~$ sudo -K
lambda@host:~$ sudo -u repomgr -i reprepro -b /var/packages/devel pull
[sudo] password for lambda:
```

If I check how `sudo` interprets it, indeed everything but the `NOPASSWD` is present for the second command:

```
lambda@host:~$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for lambda on this host:
    env_reset,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User lambda may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (repomgr) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /home/repomgr/preset-passphrase.sh,
    (repomgr) /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/reprepro -b /var/packages/devel pull
```

Why isn't this working? What would cause the `NOPASSWD` declaration to just be dropped from the second command?

Comment: You should make your edit an answer. Now people have to read all the long question in order no notice that the real problem is already solved. Even worse: They may spend some time thinking about the problem before noticing that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yeah, I was considering making it an answer, but decided to make it an edit instead since there was still the open question of why it didn't display properly. But now that I think about it, that's really just a side question, and the real question about why it didn't work was answered in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yep, it sure was something obvious as to why it wasn't working. When I had fixed the bug that I needed to add /bin/bash -c to allow the use of -i, I hadn't changed the full path for the command, `/usr/bin/reprepro`, to what I was actually passing in, `reprepro`. Changing it to use the full path as below, or likewise changing the rule to only include the command, works fine.

```
lambda@host:~$ sudo -K
lambda@host:~$ sudo -u repomgr -i /usr/bin/reprepro -b /var/packages/devel pull
```

That still leaves the puzzle of why the `NOPASSWD` isn't showing up in the `sudo -l` query, but I've solved the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have Sudo-Version 1.8.7 and the problem does not appear here:

```
sudo -l
User hl may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
    (nobody) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /home/repomgr/preset-passphrase.sh
    (nobody) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/reprepro -b /var/packages/devel pull
```

So maybe that is just a bug which has already been fixed. Maybe you can work around that by two separate statements:

```
%qa     ALL = (repomgr) NOPASSWD: REPO_LOAD_PASSPHRASE
%qa     ALL = (repomgr) NOPASSWD: REPO_PULL
```